# HTML with PHP - <script>-section code suddenly ends - bug?

Tags: javascript, php, html, intellij-idea

I encountered a very strange behaviour in php-html-mixed code. I'm using XAMPP 3.2.1 (PHP 5.2.0) and IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.

This is what my code looks like (scrubbed for readability, if you need more let me know):

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<count($stringArray); $i++) {
    $pieces = explode($GLOBALS['delimiter'], $lineData[$i]);
?>
    <div>
        ...
        <input id="<?php echo $pieces[$someValidNumber]; ?>_identifier" ...>
        ...
        <script>
            // some javascript with <?php echo $variable; ?>
        </script>
       ...
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

What happens when that loop runs n times, that for n-1 everything looks fine, but in the n-th run, within the `<script>`-section the code suddenly stops. The HTML-File ends properly with all tags closing.

This looks as following (n=4):

```
$('input[id$="MegaSteel_tons"]').val(output2);
$('#MegaSteel_cart').prop(
```

Or (n=2):

```
$('input[id$="BarZwo_meters"]').val(output2);
$('#BarZwo_cart').prop('type', 'button').change
```

Note that with an increasing n, the stop does not occur later in a deterministic way. That means when I tried n=3, the below was the result:

```
$('input[id$="Bar_meters"]').val(output2);
$('#Bar_cart').prop('type', 'button').change();
var price
```

I'm at the end of my knowledge. What causes this?

---

As requested more code:

```
$lineData = array();
$f = fopen('products.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    if (strpos($line[0], $productLine) !== false) {
        // the above produces single value arrays, thus we access them with [0]
        $pieces = explode($GLOBALS['delimiter'], $line[0]);
        $index = (int)$pieces[2];
        // todo: input must check that index is not already taken
        $lineData[$index-1] = $line[0];
    }
}
fclose($f);

ksort($lineData);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($lineData); $i++) {

    $pieces = explode($GLOBALS['delimiter'], $lineData[$i]);

    $prod_name = $pieces[0];
    $prod_lineNumber = $pieces[2];
    $prod_quantity = $pieces[3];
    $prod_tons = $pieces[4];
    $prod_meters = $pieces[5];
    $prod_pricePerTon = $pieces[6];

        ?>
        <p>
            <!-- User-Input-->
            <b> <?php echo $pieces[0]; ?></b> - <?php echo $prod_lineNumber; ?><br/>
            Units: <input id="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_quantity" type="text">
            Tons: <input id="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_tons" type="text">
            Meters: <input id="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_meters" type="text">
            Price per ton: <?php echo $prod_pricePerTon; ?>
            Calculated price: <span id="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_price">0</span>
            <input id="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_cart"
                   type="hidden" value="Add to shopping cart!"
                   onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $prod_name; ?>')">
            <!-- Auto-Update-->
            <script>
                // first field - quantity
                $('input[id$="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_quantity"]').on('keyup', function () {
                    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
                    var output1 = value * <?php echo $prod_tons . " / " . $prod_quantity; ?>;
                    var output2 = value * <?php echo $prod_meters . " / " . $prod_quantity; ?>;
                    $('input[id$="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_tons"]').val(output1);
                    $('input[id$="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_meters"]').val(output2);
                    $('#<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_cart').prop('type', 'button').change();
                    var price = output1 * <?php echo $prod_pricePerTon; ?>;
                    $('#<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_price').text(price);
                });
                // second field - tons
                $('input[id$="<?php echo $pieces[0]; ?>_tons"]').on('keyup', function () {
                    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
                    var output1 = value * <?php echo $prod_quantity . " / " . $prod_tons; ?>;
                    var output2 = value * <?php echo $prod_meters . " / " . $prod_tons; ?>;
                    $('input[id$="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_quantity"]').val(output1);
                    $('input[id$="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_meters"]').val(output2);
                    $('#<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_cart').prop('type', 'button').change();
                    var price = value * <?php echo $prod_pricePerTon; ?>;
                    $('#<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_price').text(price);
                });
                // third field - meters
                $('input[id$="<?php echo $pieces[0]; ?>_meters"]').on('keyup', function () {
                    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
                    var output1 = value * <?php echo $prod_quantity . " / " . $prod_meters; ?>;
                    var output2 = value * <?php echo $prod_tons . " / " . $prod_meters; ?>;
                    $('input[id$="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_quantity"]').val(output1);
                    $('input[id$="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_tons"]').val(output2);
                    $('#<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_cart').prop('type', 'button').change();
                    var price = output2 * <?php echo $prod_pricePerTon; ?>;
                    $('#<?php echo $prod_name; ?>_price').text(price);
                });
            </script>
        </p>
    <?php
}
?>
```

---

The delimiter accessed through the global variable is `;`. It is defined in a file called `functions.php`, that is included through `require_once("functions.php);` in the index.php (code above).

The following shows the text file being parsed (note that this is not the best solution, but is the first incremental step towards a full blown database).

```
Foo;Steel;1;20;30;40;4500.3
Bar;Copper;2;20;30;40;4500.3
BarFoo;Steel;3;20;30;40;4500.3
FooBar;Steel;2;20;30;40;4500.3
FooBear;Steel;4;20;30;40;4500.3
```

Note that the products (Foo, Bar, ...) are grouped by their product lines (Steel, Copper, ...) and then sorted by the numbers in column 3 (third value in the ;-seperated rows).

Accessing the steel-group `echo $lineData[$i]` shows the following:

```
Foo;Steel;1;20;30;40;4500.3
FooBar;Steel;2;20;30;40;4500.3
BarFoo;Steel;3;20;30;40;4500.3
```

This is as expected exactly the same as in the file being parsed.

---

Update: Changing to another php version (5.4, 5.6) does not resolve the issue.

---

Update: In Powershell "C:\xampp\php\php.exe index.php | Out-File test.html" produced an html file, that did NOT have the issue described above. So there is a workaround. I will digest further into IntelliJ IDEA.

In the meantime I also removed the `<p>...</p>` tags which did not fix the issue.

Comment: Can you show more of the source code? The current excerpt seems sound

Comment: added the surrounding code, apart from that is only plain html and js without php interference

Comment: check out your $lineData[n], maybe there is somewhere an delimiter you have not noticed.

Comment: checked that and added some description, did not find an issue there

Comment: Off topic, re PHP versions. I note that you've now commented that the problem still exists in php 5.4, but the original question was for 5.2. If you're still using php 5.2 on a production server, may I *strongly* recommend that you upgrade as soon as you can -- 5.2 has been end-of-life since early 2011. It has had no security fixes in all that time, and a significant number of *major* security holes are known to exist in it. If you're running it live on the internet, you are going to be hacked sooner or later, if you haven't been already.

Comment: Its not productive yet, and I didnt know that. Thank you!

Comment: Try removing the starting and closing `<p>` tag. I've had problems with using `<p>` tag inside loops. For some reason, they don't seem to follow a start-close pattern

Comment: @michaelbahr if you're not in production yet, then rather than just going with php5.4, why not consider going all the way up to the latest PHP version, PHP 5.6.

Comment: @asprin that did not fix it :/

Comment: @Simba will try that next

Comment: I copied your entire `for` loop and used random values for the variables and ran the loop. I can't seem to reproduce your issue. It's outputting fine at my end.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top could be useful.

Comment: @Simba: did not resolve the issue

Comment: @asprin: Thanks for trying. Will maybe use another machine.

Comment: @absalon.valdes: Will try that next :)

Comment: in this test `if (strpos($line[0], $productLine) !== false)` what is `$productLine` ?

Comment: @AlexAndrei: ``$line[0]`` contains an array like ``["productName", "productLine", "number", ...]``. ProductLine is something like ``steel``. This if/else sorts out ``productLines`` that shall not be displayed in a specific category page.

Comment: [**PHPFiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YuAKzd) If you view the source code of the output, you'll see that everthing is being renedered without any problem. So your code's fine. The culprit must be something else...

Comment: @michaelbahr join chat please so I can ask you more questions  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84053/html-with-php-script-section-code-suddenly-ends-bug

Comment: Thanks to @AlexAndrei I found a workaround described in the recent update. However the issue is not solved yet.

Comment: @michaelbahr have you tried to use an output buffer (ob functionalities) to build the page and then output it all at once? Do you still face the same issue? This should be like running it from the command line as you have already done

Comment: Have you tried saving the script section into a string and then putting that string inside the script? This way you can take the script out of the loop, maybe that's causing the problem (too many scripts tags). When you run this, do you see something in the console?

Comment: Your real problem is you're cooking spaghetti: the mix of languages and logic.

Comment: Sorry but it is really ugly spaghetti code, I can not even read it. You want to pass product information from server to javascript. You can basically  define a product in php as a object and past it to a variable as JSON once and use the javascript variable in the rest of the code.

Comment: Sorry that the code is shit, yes thats my real problem. I will work on that.


However the problem in this question is that IntelliJ IDEA produces something different than using XAMPP or Powershell as described in the update above (using exactly the same php.exe). 


Thank you all for your help! I will put a ticket at IntelliJ and answer this question with the workaround and ticket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want a fish or to learn to fish ?

> "Make it simple, as simple as possible. No more." A.Einstein

Okay, it is maybe a simple answer, but true. **You cannot maintain/debug such a spaghetti code** in a reasonnable amount of time. Look at the time you loose about this issue. Even with a bounty, you get few luck to solve it, cause talented people dont pay time on such a code.

Your code is clean. No critics. But your **method** is not. I experienced such cases very often in 10 years of coding. Hours lost, energy expenses. Clarify it all, simplify, synthetize, the failure will appear. Your code will be stronger.

That's my genuine answer.

Comment: Thank you for that input. I will take it for my further path in web-dev. However I am quite happy that I'm actually getting this kind of project done with my current knowledge.

Talking about better practices: How would you produce HTML/JavaScript-Code that builds dynamically depending on the server ressources? Where can I learn that?

Comment: @michaelbahr Once you know coding ( and you do - mixing various language like in your question - ), think architecture. See big blocks and no more lines. Quickly - between 2 works here - I'd say I'd prefer a some Ajax Code ("would you produce HTML/JavaScript-Code that builds dynamically depending on the server ressources" => AJAX). AJAX and JSON. Then work all the code HTML/JS, no more PHP. I had such errors cause of <? ?> too much inside HTML/JS.

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lineData)+1; $i++)
```

should give you an "Undefined offset" notice, try replacing it with

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lineData); $i++)
```

also, I think you have to be sure that

```
$lineData[$index-1] = $line[0];
```

produces an array with *all* indexes from 0 to count($lineData)-1

Comment: Thanks for the input. However this does not fix the sudden stop of code generation. The +1 was a dev fix for an issue that will be adressed later in another question. I will remove that from the my code above.
$lineData does have all indexes from 0 to count($lineData)-1. Those are 0,1,2.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beggining of your script. It might be that php is throwing an error and not showing it. With these commands you'll activate error reporting and show those errors.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try make something like that:

```
<?php
$body = 'your javasrcipr text';
for ($i = 0; $i<count($lineData); $i++) {
    print_r($body);
}?>
```

and check what it makes to your website

Comment: I meant you just check does the error occurrs in this case. On this depends where you should looking for likely misstake